# Regular expression for subnet masking?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using regular expression for checking the subnet masking. I use ajax txtbox with masking value but that is not working, then I switched to a textbox and applying a regular expression for that. unfortunatly that one is also not working.

Can you help me out to give a RE for subnet masking 255.255.255.255

Or any best way to do that?

**Solution**:

I was using masked text box and don't know how to put validation expression.

Finally I found a property of masked text box as validation expression, and there I put the RE and change the property validate to true.

No need to use validator expression explicitly.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be be faster and easier to just write a function that converts the mask to an integer and checks for contiguous bits on left (msb) side.

Comment: By reading this http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Subnet/6.htm it seems the number of "valid" numbers is quite small.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to accept **any IP address** as a subnet mask:

```
var num = @"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})";
var rx = new Regex("^" + num + @"\." + num + @"\." + num + @"\." + num + "$");
```

I considered easier to split the "repeating" match for a single group of numbers in a separate variable.

As an exercise for the reader, I'll give another variant of the expression. This one will capture all the numbers in the same group but different captures:

```
var rx = new Regex("^(?:" + num + @"(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}$");
```

**BUT it's wrong, you should use this**

```
var num = @"(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)";
var rx = new Regex("^" + num + @"\." + num + @"\." +num + @"\." +num + "$");
```

or

```
var rx = new Regex("^(?:" + num + @"(?:\.(?!$)|$)){4}$");
```

http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Subnet/6.htm

Comment: This is close but not all the way correct. For example, this code would mark 254.0.0.0 as valid (it's not). It would also mark something like 255.255.0.128 as valid (it's not). The best way to do this is convert the ip address to bits and check for the first occurrence of a '0' and go from there. https://kthx.at/subnetmask/

Answer (score 13):

To do this with a regular expression, you have to ensure that the entire IPv4 dotted quad represents a 32 bit number with leading ones only. It is not enough to ensure that each number in the quad has only leading ones. For example, 255.192.255.0 is not a valid submask, even though each number in the quad has only leading ones. Building on the solution offered by @xanatos,

`var leadingOnes = new Regex("255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+");`

defines a regular expression that will match any 8-bit (decimal) number with leading ones only. I have used "0+" to allow for .000, which is sometimes used in quads. Obviously, if you want to force a singe zero, use "0" instead.

You then have to build up a regular expression that matches any one of the four following patterns, which I represent as pseudo regular expressions to make it easer to understand:

- 255.255.255.**leadingOnes**
- 255.255.**leadingOnes***.0
- 255.**leadingOnes**.0.0
- **leadingOnes**.0.0.0

You can either write this out as a single string, or build it up through concatenation. Here's building it up:

```
var leadingOnes = "(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+);"
var allOnes = @"(255\.)"; 
var re = new Regex("^((" + allOnes + "{3}" + leadingOnes + ")|" +
                     "(" + allOnes + "{2}" + leadingOnes + @"\.0+)|" +
                     "(" + allOnes +         leadingOnes + @"(\.0+){2})|" +
                     "(" +                   leadingOnes + @"(\.0+){3}))$");
```

And here's the entire string, if we ignore line breaks.

`var re = new Regex(@"^(((255\.){3}(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+))|((255\.){2}(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)\.0)|((255\.)(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)(\.0+){2})|((255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)(\.0+){3}))$");`

Following @Keith's suggestion, you could start with a simple regular expression such as

`Regex("([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"` to get four 3-digit numbers separated by dots, and then write a function that extracts and evaluates the four pieces into a 32-bit integer that you then check to ensure that it has only leading ones. <strike>There are several ways to do that, but all of them require up to 31 compare operations to complete the validation.</strike>

Comment: You can easily check to see if an int contains only leading ones with some bit arithmetic and a single comparison: `i == i | (i << 1)`

Comment: In case anyone else uses above, the string assiged to `leadingOnes` above is missing a `|` between `224` and `192`

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to mention that I didn't find the missing pipe bug, pmarquis did.

Comment: Thanks @Dave. Fixed. Hard to believe that answer has been there for four and half years, and just no being noticed.

Comment: @Bevan for people who don't know the <<-sign, it's called bitshift operator.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question asked about a Regex expression, but for anyone else who's interested, here are two iterative solutions to the problem.  The second function is a bit faster than the first.

```
private bool IsValidSubnet(IPAddress ip) {
    byte[] validOctets = new byte[] { 255, 254, 252, 248, 240, 224, 192, 128, 0 };
    byte[] ipOctets = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    bool restAreZeros = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (!validOctets.Contains(ipOctets[i]))
            return false;
        if (restAreZeros && ipOctets[i] != 0)
            return false;
        if (ipOctets[i] < 255)
            restAreZeros = true;
    }
    return true;
}

// checks if the address is all leading ones followed by only zeroes
private bool IsValidSubnet2(IPAddress ip) {
    byte[] ipOctets = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    bool restAreOnes = false;
    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            bool bitValue = (ipOctets[i] >> j & 1) == 1;
            if (restAreOnes && !bitValue)
                return false;
            restAreOnes = bitValue;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From http://pastebin.com/wTEKjKpP

```
var subnetRegex = /^((128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0\.0)|(255\.(((0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0\.0)|(255\.(((0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)\.0)|255\.(0|128|192|224|240|248|252|254)))))$/
```

Of course that's for javascript, but that should help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this regex to validate subnet

```
^(((255\.){3}(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128+))|((255\.){2}(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)\.0)|((255\.)(255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)(\.0+){2})|((255|254|252|248|240|224|192|128|0+)(\.0+){3}))$
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

A little late to the party, but we can't do just a regex check on valid octets  because:

1. A subnet **must** start with 255.X.X.X
2. A subnet **cannot** look like this: 255.254.128.X - once there is 0 bit, everything else must be 0 afterwards

The correct way to do this is to walk the bits from the MSB, checking for the first 0 bit. Once you discover the first 0 bit, check what position it's in. The largest legal subnet is a /8, or 255.0.0.0, meaning there needs to be 8 1 bits before the first zero. Then, make sure every bit after the first 0 is a zero. So in summary:

1. (Optionally verify that it's even a valid IP address...)
2. Start at MSB, walk down bits looking for the first 0
3. If you find a 0 (255.255.255.255 would still be valid), check position
4. Check that all remaining bits are zero

### Code

```
    private bool IsValidSubnet(string subnet)
    {
        //A subnet is a valid ipv4 address, so start checking there
        if (!IsIPv4(subnet)) return false;

        // Get the 4 bytes
        byte[] subnetMaskBytes =
                    System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(subnet).GetAddressBytes();

        //Shift to get uint representation of the bits
        var UintSubnet = (uint)subnetMaskBytes[0] << 24;
        UintSubnet += (uint)subnetMaskBytes[1] << 16;
        UintSubnet += (uint)subnetMaskBytes[2] << 8;
        UintSubnet += (uint)subnetMaskBytes[3];

        int i = 31;
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            UInt32 mask = (UInt32)(1 << i);
            if ((UintSubnet & mask) == 0) break;
            i--;
        }

        // It is not legal to have fewer than 8 bits of addressing
        if (i >= 24) return false;

        // Make sure that all remaining bits are 0
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            UInt32 mask = (UInt32)(1 << i);
            if ((UintSubnet & mask) != 0) return false;
            i--;
        }
        return true;
    }
```