# Regular Expression to Match IP Subnet

Tags: c#, regex, ip

I need a C# regular expression that will match an IP Subnet, like "127.65.231", but not match an IP Address on the subnet, like "127.65.231.111".  I had found this Regex for an IP Address:

> @"\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b"

and was thinking I could just delete the part that checks the last octet, like this:

> @"\b\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\b"

but this matches both the IP Address and the Subnet.  Can anyone help with this?

Comment: IP addresses are in octets ranging from 0 to 255. Your regex will match invalid octets such as `400`. If you want it more exact, the regex will be more complex.

Comment: Yes as @BrianStephens said your regex will match 999 too which is not at all a valid IP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for subnet masking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360768/regular-expression-for-subnet-masking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@"^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$"
```

use [Line Anchors.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)  Add ^ at the beginning of your Regex, and $ at the end, to verify the beginning and end of the input.

This will match `127.65.231` but not `127.65.231.111`

Comment: It will also match 999.999.999 which is not valid.

Comment: @Eric Lippert, I see that now from my tests, but how would I change it to match only valid ip octets, not above 255 each?

Comment: There are only 256 of them. Just list them. :)

Comment: more seriously: this is really not a great problem for regular expressions to solve. If it's not clear how to use the tool to solve the problem, you might be using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a lookahead. Also, please escape the `.` characters—otherwise it would match *any* character:

```
@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(?=\.\d{1,3})\b"
```

This will match any string like `127.65.231` as long as it's followed by a string like `.111`.