# Regex Valid IP adresse with mask

Tags: regex, ip-address

I have an issue with my regex i have this

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" pattern="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\/(3[0-2]|[0-2][0-9]|[0-9]))\b" placeholder="Adresse IP" ID="Ip_address" runat="server" />
```

So this is my regex

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?\/(3[0-2]|[0-2][0-9]|[0-9]))\b
```

When the IP Adress is under 200.200.200.200 it forces the user to add the mask /1 for exemple but when it's equal or above it doesn't work

What I have actually

`1.1.1.1` -> force `/something` so it work

`199.199.199.199` -> force `/something` so it work

`200.200.200.200` -> doesn't force `/something` so it doesn't work

`250.250.250.250` -> doesn't force `/something` so it doesn't work

Comment: `pattern` regex must match the whole input string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't understand what do u want to say

Comment: Have you checked out this previous question and its answers?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360768/regular-expression-for-subnet-masking

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I do it in the pattern cause I have a formvalidation after I try
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51148542/10863293 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978652/10863293 it doesn't work

Maybe I don't add them properly I don't know. I just copy/paste

Comment: I just mentioned what I mentioned because you are using `\b`, word boundaries, without probably realizing they are meaningless here, as in fact the whole regex is put in between `^(?:` and `)$` and is thus anchored.  I am not sure what you mean by "force" and "doesn't work/work". Regex matches a string or does not. What are the inputs that you want to match? Can you supply a couple of those? And those that should not match?

Comment: Hm, I re-read the question another time, please try `^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\/(?:3[0-2]|[0-2]?[0-9])$` and let know if it is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you group that parts of your regex correctly. You can use

```php
^(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\/(?:3[0-2]|[0-2]?[0-9])$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q06KKL/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)` - an octet pattern
- `(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}` - three occurrences of a `.` and an octet pattern
- `\/` - a `/` char
- `(?:3[0-2]|[0-2]?[0-9])` - `3` and then `0`, `1`, or `2`, or an optional `0`, `1` or `2` followed with any single digit.
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

We can use this regular expression for IP validation

```
 ^((2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{0,2})\.){3}(2[0-5][0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]?[0-9]{0,2})$
```